# Mosquitto Error

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I am using Mosquitto for my project.
I have installed mosquitto-1.4.8-install-win32.exe and also place the three binary in folder 
1. pthreadVC2.dll
2. libeay32.dll
3. ssleay32.dll

And reinstalled the mosquitto after that Started the services for mosquitto broker I entered following commands in cmd

```
*C:\Users\ravindra-s>netstat -an
Active Connections
  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  ...
  TCP    0.0.0.0:912            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1883           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:2701           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3306           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  ...
  TCP    [::]:135               [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:445               [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:1883              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:2701              [::]:0                 LISTENING
 ...
C:\Users\ravindra-s>cd "c:\Program Files"
c:\Program Files>cd mosquitto
c:\Program Files\mosquitto>mosquitto -v
1455619440: mosquitto version 1.4.8 (build date 14/02/2016 15:33:31.09) starting
1455619440: Using default config.
1455619440: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1455619440: Error: Unknown error*
```

It doesn't show that "Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883." and shows error now.
Previously my system  does not show this error. but Now it is showing and my application is not running properly.

Please tell me to resolve this issue.

Any Help appreciated .

Thanks and Regards,
Ravindra

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you already have mosquitto broker running and it's failing to open the ports (beacause they are already open).

Those lines shows that the 1883 (mqtt port) is already open...

```
 TCP    0.0.0.0:1883           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 TCP    [::]:1883              [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

Comment: Maybe , I have MQTT Client installed in android phone ,earlier I was able to connect publish message and also getting the messages in subscribed topic ,but Now I can't it shows unable to connect. I have a laptop with Windows 10 64bit i am facing same error with it also .

Answer (score 1):

It may be due to windows running services of mosquitto.

First Stop mosquitto from windows services list

1.Press the Windows+R keys to open the Run dialog, type services.msc, press Enter

2.Search for mosquitto broker service

3.Stop the service

Now enter cmd as usual `c:\Program Files\mosquitto>mosquitto -v`
This will Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.

as below

```
1455619440: Using default config.

1455619440: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.

1455619440: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
```

Hope this will help you.